# После копирования HDD система видит не весь размер

Tags: hdd

Скопировал старый HDD, объемом 1 Тб на новый 2 Тб. Копировал из линукса,утилитой ddrescue. Собственно все прошло отлично, если бы не одно но: отображается 1 Тб вместо 2-х. Как это исправить теперь? Копировать заново очень-очень не хочется, т.к. процедура заняла 5 часов.
chkdsk оповестил о неверной битовой карте тома.
chkdsk /f не дал никаких результатов.
[image: Управление дисками и проводник]

[image: Управление дисками]

Comment: С какими параметрами вы запускали ddrescue?

Comment: ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 /dev/sdd1 mapfile

Comment: и еще раз прогнал chkdsk - ошибок не обнаружено

Comment: Попробуйте `DISKPART> extend filesystem`

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: DISKPART> extend filesystem все же помогло
спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В командной строке:
diskpart
DISKPART> extend filesystem